# Get generic class at compile time

Tags: java, generics, compile-time

While I know you cannot actually get the type of a generic at runtime because of type erasure, I was wondering if it is possible to get it at compile time.

```
class ObjectHandle<T extends ObjType> {
    T obj;
    void setObj(T o) {
        obj = o;
    }
}

class ObjType {}
class SubObjType extends ObjType {}

...
ObjectHandle<SubObjType> handle = new ObjectHandle<SubObjType>();
...
ObjType obj = [method that returns an ObjType];
if(obj instanceof [handle's generic class, here SubObjType]) {
    handle.setObj(obj); // cast???
}
```

Here the compiler knows the type of the generic of `handle` and what I want is something so I don't have to change the type of `handle` and the `instanceof` check (and the cast) when I decide to change the class (in the code, not at runtime of course).

Comment: but compiler does not know the type of `obj`, so you have to use `instanceof`  anyway.

Comment: That looks like all you want is a shorthand for your SubObjType, something you could do in C with a typedef. Java doesn't have that.

Comment: If you don't need general-case code, and your only concern is that the actual class might change in the code, I'd just replace the `if` with `assert handle instanceof SubObjType`.  Or do you really want the `handle.setObj` call to be skipped if and when the actual type is changed in the code?

Comment: @VGR: The ideal thing would be a method in ObjectHandle to ensure that `setObj()` gets the correct class and otherwise throw an exception or something. This is just a workaround for that problem. I have a method which loads objects of different subclasses from a file and returns them as the super class (ObjType). While `obj` SHOULD be a returned SubObjType, there is no way to tell other than using `instanceof` on it.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov: Why would the compiler need to know that? `obj` is a `ObjType`, so checking it against a subclass of `ObjType` seems valid to me. The compiler should not erase the `instanceof`, but the `[handle's generic class, here SubObjType]` and replace it with `[ObjectHandle<  __SubObjType__  > handle] => SubObjType`.

Comment: Do you know, while coding, what the possible subclasses are?  Or do you need true general-case code, where there may exist a theoretically unlimited (or at least unknown) number of subclasses of ObjType?

Comment: @VGR: In theory, I do, but more classes are likely to get added. Adding a class should not require more code than the class itself, so no need for a complicated approach. ;-) I was just wondering if I can make use of some compile-time magic, but it seems I can't. After all, it's not such a big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since generic types are subjected to erasure, you will need to specify the java.lang.Class somewhere in the code.  One way is to pass it to a generic method:

```
ObjType obj = /*...*/;
handleObj(obj, SubObjType.class);

// ...

private <T extends ObjType> void handleObj(ObjType obj,
                                           ObjectHandle<T> handle,
                                           Class<T> handleableObjClass) {
    if (handleableObjClass.isInstance(obj)) {
        handle.setObj(handleableObjClass.cast(obj));
    }
}
```

If you don't know what subclasses of ObjType you're looking for, you will need to add a reifiable Class property to ObjectHandle, similar to how java.util.EnumSet and java.util.EnumMap do it:

```
class ObjectHandle<T extends ObjType> {

    T obj;

    private final Class<T> objectClass;

    ObjectHandle(Class<T> cls) {
        objectClass = Objects.requireNonNull(cls);
    }

    Class<T> getObjectClass() {
        return objectClass;
    }

    void setObj(T o) {
        obj = o;
    }
}

// ...
ObjectHandle<SubObjType> handle = new ObjectHandle<SubObjType>();
// ...

ObjectType obj = /*...*/;
if (handle.getObjectClass().isInstance(obj)) {
    handle.setObj(handle.getObjectClass().cast(obj));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's how I would have done it as well. No cool compile-time way, sadly. This does not really answer what I was looking for, but that's because there seems to be no answer to this. Anyway, thanks for clearing this up. :)